# Can I deal double magic damage with Udyr's Tiger stance?

Tags: league-of-legends

From the description of [Udyr](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Udyr_the_Animal_Spirit)'s Tiger Stance:

> (Stance) – Activation: Udyr's next attack will deal his current attack
>   damage in addition to magic damage over 2 seconds.

If Udyr selects tiger stance, waits for the cooldown to refresh, attacks an opponent, then re-activates tiger stance and attacks again, what will happen?  Is the magic damage dealt twice?

Comment: I can't say with 100% certainty (so not posting as answer), but it is most likely a unique buff that grants on next hit magic damage. If that is the case, no, it won't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Been maining udyr for a couple of months (a source for the answer)

Basically, the buff is extended, not doubled. You still deal the same damage over 2 seconds, but the damage may be extended to 3 or 4 seconds depending on when you apply the buff. If you look closer, you see that udyrs bleed ticks for half the displayed damage every second for 2 seconds.

Assuming you deal 100 damage over 2 seconds, and strike your opponent again with the buff directly after the 1st tick:

1. 50 damage after 1 second
2. *bleed reapplied*
3. 100 damage after 2 seconds
4. 150 damage after 3 seconds

Tl;Dr - you dont apply a 2nd stack of the bleed effect. You simply prolong the initial effect.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, if you proc tiger stance as your first attack, then activate tiger stance again, it deals the bonus damage.